# Blender live-action footage and Grease Pencil animation

Tags: animation, video-sequence-editor, grease-pencil, 2d

I have a bit of live-action footage that I would like to incorporate into a scene done with Grease Pencil to. Think of a newscaster talking about something and the live-action video is in a smaller window on the screen. Where the newscaster and set are done in Grease Pencil and the video they're talking about is live-action. I've brought the live-action footage into the video sequencer and I will be editing the live-action footage with pauses. The live-action footage will not fill the screen. it will only take up about 25% of one part of the screen.

Is there a way to see the video from the video sequencer in the Grease Pencil view? It would be helpful to be able to see the video sequencer video while working on the character in Grease Pencil.

If not, is there a workflow that would help with this?

Thanks,
Jim

Comment: you can import images as planes and select a video in order to add a video in your scene and not just in the background

Comment: Related: [How to easily draw a grease pencil image on top of an image](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/170988/how-to-easily-draw-a-grease-pencil-on-top-of-an-image)

Answer (score 3):

The grease pencil works only in the 3D viewport, you can't use it on the VSE or in the Movie Clip Editor.

Here are a couple of options:

**1. Use video as background for the camera**. Select the camera object and, in the camera option tab, check *Background image -> Add image -> Movie*, then select your video file there.

This way you will see the video through the camera view (<kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> ).

[image]

Note that the background image will not render unless you use it in the *compositor*, and mix your render layer using *Alpha over*.

Make sure that *Film* is set to *transparent* and the *view transform* for *color management* is set to *Standard*.

[image]

Change the resolution in the *Output* tab for the project so that it matches the dimensions, and the frame rate of the original video. Also remember to render at 100% of the resolution.

---

**2. Alternatively, use the video as texture on the world**.

Set the *color* to use the image texture, and select the video there. Set the *vector coordinates* to *Window*. and the *extrapolation* to *Clip*

In this case you need to disable the film transparent settings to make the background renderable. No need to use the compositor in this case.

To view the background enable *Scene World* and *Scene Lights*

[image]

Comment: I can't find any way to add a VSE sequence as a movie clip, though --- while there's a drop-down of existing movie clips, I haven't found out how to get my VSE sequence to show up there. Do I need to name the sequence somehow? If so, how?