# Grease Pencil Onto video

Tags: grease-pencil

How do I draw gp onto video? I have found many of the same question that were answered but there is a teal camera icon that isn't appearing for me, I am in blender 2.90

Comment: Related: [How to easily draw a grease pencil on top of an image](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/170988/how-to-easily-draw-a-grease-pencil-on-top-of-an-image) and [Live action footage and grease pencil animation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/139155/blender-live-action-footage-and-grease-pencil-animation)

Answer (score 2):

Start with the template for 2d animation.

[image]

Set the color management to sRGB, the view transform to Standard and the look to None.

[image]

Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to enter Edit mode.

In the outliner select the camera.

[image]

In the properties window select camera and enable Background Image.

Set the source to Movie Clip, select your file and set the opacity to 100%

[image]

This will allow you to use the video as background image when you are looking trough the camera view. (Note that this image is for reference only, and will not render without setting it up in the outliner)

Select stroke on the outliner (or create a new one using Add > Grease Pencil > Blank).

Enter draw mode and draw on top of the background video.

[image]

To render the grease pencil along with the video, set film > Transparent

[image]

Then set the compositor with a movie clip node with the video and the render layer and use alpha over to composite them together.

[image]

Comment: I included this in the question but the camera icon on the right side of the screen is just not there, not the one at the top right but more of mid right.

Comment: Please call things by their name...Do you mean in the "properties" window? If you don't see the camera, well, that means you have not selected the camera. In the outliner right -clik on the camera and choose select