# How can I combine work that I've done in the "video editing" and "2D Animation" tabs in the same project on a render?

Tags: rendering, animation, video-sequence-editor, text-object

I have a 2D animation and some work done in the "video editing" tab. When I "render animation", the only thing that renders is the text and music that I have done in "video editing"; it does not include the animation that I've done. How can I render both tabs into one video?

Comment: @susu I'm actually having problems creating scene strips, so I was hoping to find a general solution.

Comment: Try turning off compositing and sequencing in the render output tab. Then try compositing that video seperately?

Comment: @NascentSpace I turned them off, but what do you mean by "compositing that video separately"? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Instead of rendering and compositing at the same time just plugging in the animation with the audio and text overlayed

Comment: @NascentSpace I am so sorry, but I don't know how to plug in the animation with the audio and text overlayed. I'm having a hard time getting used to the Blender learning curve, and searching for how to do these simple tasks seem to get buried under more complicated material. Do i do this under "render > animation"?

Comment: @NascentSpace if you're referring to using scene clips, I'm having a problem figuring out how to generate these scene clips.

Comment: @NascentSpace I finally learned how to put a scene clip in the VSE, but when I render, it's still not compiling everything together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to add a scene into the VSE with a scene strip, you'll have to make a new scene for the VSE contents, as shown in this gif(from this post: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/184931/37272):

[image]

To render from the VSE you'll need to check this box:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! You don't know how long I was messing around with the software ready to damage the hardware out of rage. This was perfect!