# How can i set up 2d animation in a preexisting video editing workspace

Tags: animation, video-sequence-editor, 2d

So I've switched toolsets from first creating animations in an external tool and doing the video editing in blender, to now doing the 2d animation and editing all directly in blender.
I have learned a few of the basics of 2d animation in blender with the help of youtube, and now I want to switch my existing video to blenders 2d animation but I can't get it to work properly.

So I want to keep the previous clips and editing I've already created (which was in a basic editing workspace), but now I want to continue with blender 2d animation from this point forward. The problem is that if I switch to the `2d animation` tab, it displays a 3d workspace and I have no idea how I can set it up so I can start drawing and animating like in the tutorials I've used before (which started with a 2d animation workspace).

I have of course searched and tried stuff out to get it working. For example I've tried to add a new scene like in [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/187618/how-can-i-combine-work-that-ive-done-in-the-video-editing-and-2d-animation), I've tried `add` a blank grease pencil object, added layers, a cameras etc, but I've never gotten things set up so I could just have a canvas that I could simply draw upon.

Comment: 2-D animation in blender actually occurs within the 3-D space. Drawings are one or more grease pencil objects. Do you know this?

Comment: @TheLabCat yes I am aware of this, but like i said in the question I've tried to get it set up with a camera etc, but I couldn't draw or zoom in/out to see the canvas borders like when you start a 2d animation workspace. I suspect it's just setup, but i don't know how to do it.